# Как разделить строку нa одинаковые части python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Например превратить строку
`"123abchhhooi"` в 
`["123", "abc", "hhh", "ooi"]`?

Comment: Было бы полезнее добавить к существующим ответам вариант с `textwrap`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно использовать модуль textwrap (standard library):

```
import textwrap
s = "123abchhhooi"
print(textwrap.wrap(s, 3))
```

***stdout:***

> `["123", "abc", "hhh", "ooi"]`

Альтернативно regex:

```
import re
s = "123abchhhooi"
re.findall('[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3}', s)
```

***stdout:***

> `["123", "abc", "hhh", "ooi"]`

Comment: [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21351275/split-a-string-to-even-sized-chunks)

Answer (score 1):

Ещё как вариант.

```
s = "123abchhhooi"
print([s[i:i + 3] for i in range(0, len(s), 3)])
```